Are there compact sets in the first uncountable ordinal space [0, $\omega_1$), which are not $G_\delta$?
It is known that the space [0, $\omega_1$) with order topology is not perfectly normal, which means that there exists closed set, which is not $G_\delta$. I've read through the proof, and the reason, why it is not perfectly normal, is that the set of all limit ordinals is not $G_\delta$.
This set is closed but not compact, since it is also the limit ordinal, which is not compact in order topology.
So I wonder, are there compact sets in [0, $\omega_1$), which are not $G_\delta$?
Could you please provide me with some example or idea of the proof, that all are $G_\delta$?
I thought of some easy example, but haven't come across one.

Any compact subset of $[0,\omega_1)$ is bounded, i.e., it's a subset of $[0,\alpha)$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$.  And $[0,\alpha)$ can be embedded (preserving order and topology) in the reals. So it's metrizable and therefore perfectly normal.
